# How to send content continuously to browser in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to reproduce the jenkins console output functionality for a client in Primefaces.

The user start an action by calling a bean method.
A new Thread is started to execute a time consuming method.
The bean method ends and the page is render while the thread is still running.

The thread will add some new items in a List or in an InputStream (whatever) as soon as the new items are available.

What I want know is to update the client's browser as soon as the new content is available from the server.

I do not know how to implement such a functionality in Primefaces.
How can I do that?

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are "poll" or "push".

Comment: `poll` sound great, I will try that.